# Mongoose returning null on find() query

Tags: node.js, mongoose

My complete code is this, I check online and applied all the solutions but it didn't helped me.

```
    mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/onlinepharmacy", {useNewUrlParser:true ,useUnifiedTopology : true});

const mediciSchema = {
    title: String,
    desc: String,
    price: String,
    type: String,
    status: String
}; 

const Medicine = mongoose.model("Medicine",mediciSchema);

//sugar
index.get("/sugar", function(req,res){
    Medicine.find(function(err,sugarMed){
        console.log(sugarMed);
    });
});
```

Comment: What should it find? You didn't provide any search argument to the `find` call.  
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find

Comment: I added arguments but it doesnt work idk why

Comment: have you checked, If it is giving an error?

Comment: it is returning null

Answer (score 0):

you should tell the mongoose to find all Medicine, `{}` told DB to show all the Medicine

```
Medicine.find({}, function(err,sugarMed){
    console.log(sugarMed);
});
```

Comment: are you sure that the onlinepharmacy has a data in it ?

Answer (score 0):

It is solved I changed the collection name from medicine to medicines. Thanks everyone